# What is the difference between deficient, scant, scarce, meager? how to use them?

Tags: word-difference

Concerning the words **deficient**, **scant**, **scarce**, **meager**: I read somewhere that:

> The four are related and the meanings overlap at times, but they are not quite the same.

Can anyone explain? thanks.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Suraj. We expect people do do a little research before asking a question, and include details of that research in the question. You can then ask questions specifically about what you don't understand in the information that you have found. Here is a good place to look up the words: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deficient

Comment: Also, posting the same question to both ELL and ELU is something we discourage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Deficient** - not enough.

  > Their funds were deficient, so they couldn't buy food.
- **Scant** and **scarce** - thinly populated; rare in the area.

  > Because it was Winter, the fields had scant crops, and the wildlife was scarce.
- **Meager** - the bare minimum.

  > Their meal was meager, so they were still hungry.